# How to insert script tags into end of body tag in dnn?

Tags: javascript, html, dotnetnuke-7

I use dnn7 for implement my website. I want to insert java script files into end of body tag .I use this  codes in end of my skin file.

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="DnnJsInclude2" runat="server" FilePath="js/my_JavaScript.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="DnnJsInclude" runat="server" FilePath="js/bootstrap.min.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
```

But when run  dnn by IIS and see the page source  , I  understand  that dnn auto move my java scripts files to   first of body tag.
 How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code and my problem solved. You can add your js files  to end line of your skin like this code:

```
<script src="<%=SkinPath%>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```